# The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client' not registered or could not be loaded

Tags: asp.net, oracle, entity-framework, ado.net, edmx

When I try to open my edmx file in my Asp.Net web application this error show up:

*Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error Error 175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.*

Another edmx file, which is connected to Sql Server, doesn't have problem, opens without any errors.

Comment: Did you install the ODP.NET provider?

Answer (score 1):

ODP.NET Managed provider is from Oracle. To use it you must have it installed on your machine so that the assembly can be found.

- Reference ODP.NET (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework) from NuGet
- using namespace
- then rebuild your project

Answer (score 0):

In my case it is was a duplicate of invariant name in machine.config after installation of ODP.NET.

Solution Ι found in **web.config** to the start of **system.data** > **DbProviderFactories** add following line

`<remove invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"></remove>`